# Laravel Valet - Server Connection Refused or slow

Tags: localhost

Been having issues with Laravel's Valet the whole day. Either I cannot load the site in the browser or it hangs. Sometimes restarting my Mac works. Sometimes restarting valet works. I am running in with Homebrew's MariaDB and PHP70

```
brew services list
Name    Status  User   Plist
dnsmasq started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
mariadb started jasper /Users/jasper/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
php70   started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php70.plist
tor     stopped
```

Currently I tried to go back to plugins overview and it hangs now.

Doing a netstat check gets me a really long list:

```
sudo netstat -tnlp tcp | grep '\.80 '
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54080        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54079        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54080        127.0.0.1.80           ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54078        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54079        127.0.0.1.80           ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54077        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54078        127.0.0.1.80           ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54076        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54077        127.0.0.1.80           ESTABLISHED
tcp4    1318      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54075        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54076        127.0.0.1.80           ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54075        127.0.0.1.80           ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  178.20.172.186.54074   205.196.223.93.80      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  178.20.172.186.54073   205.196.223.93.80      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  178.20.172.186.54072   192.0.73.2.80          ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  178.20.172.186.54071   192.0.73.2.80          ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  178.20.172.186.54062   151.101.193.69.80      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  178.20.172.186.54059   151.101.193.69.80
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54046        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54045        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54044        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54045        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54044        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4    1362      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54043        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4    1100      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.54042        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54043        127.0.0.1.80               CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.53966        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.53725        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.53725        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.53713        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.53713        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.53712        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.53712        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.53711        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.53710        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.53711        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           127.0.0.1.53709        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.53710        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2 
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.53709        127.0.0.1.80           FIN_WAIT_2
```

Here lsof minus Google and DropBox:

```
lsof -i tcp
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld      559 jasper   25u  IPv4 0xee33df006c9199f1      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)
TextMate   3408 jasper    7u  IPv6 0xee33df005c2a2ea1      0t0  TCP localhost:52698 (LISTEN)
php-fpm   12857 jasper    0u  IPv4 0xee33df006e0ced19      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm   12858 jasper    0u  IPv4 0xee33df006e0ced19      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm   12879 jasper    0u  IPv4 0xee33df006e0ced19      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
```

stoppping and starting Valet gets me back into the local WordPress installation again. But it still does not explain the issue with connection to site.dev getting refused nor the slowness of it all. Valet is supposed to run will with WordPress.
I checked for PHP running:

```
ps aux | grep php
jasper          11529   0.0  0.0  2442020   2060 s000  S+    2:54PM   0:00.00 grep php
jasper          11501   0.0  0.0  2517648   3716   ??  S     2:51PM   0:00.07 /usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf
jasper          11499   0.0  0.3  2588136  46876   ??  S     2:51PM   0:01.29 /usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf
jasper          11492   0.0  0.1  2564648  18824   ??  S     2:51PM   0:00.93 /usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf
root            11487   0.0  0.1  2481744  11428   ??  Ss    2:51PM   0:00.04 /usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf
```

and that seems to be ok. No apache running either. 
Valet logs shows me zero info:

```
valet logs
No log files were found.
```

After trying to go the plugins page I get

```
This site can’t be reached

site.dev refused to connect.
Search Google for domain pure dev admin plugins
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I can however ping the site

```
ping site.dev
PING site.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.118 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.141 ms
^C
--- site.dev ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.049/0.103/0.141/0.039 ms
```

How can I debug the issue further?

Comment: Hmm it may the VPN connection. Just saw the ip and decided to turn it off. Trying some stuff again now. Still now sure why this would be an issue though.

Comment: Nope, on installation third plugin connection refused again.. only one tcp4 connection now: sudo netstat -tnlp tcp | grep '\.80 '
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.101.55064    151.101.1.69.80        ESTABLISHED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I uninstalled and reinstalled Valet and also updated to 1.1.22 from 1.1.19. Before that I increased PHP memory limit to `memory_limit = 512M` in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini` I also upped max execution time to 300: `max_execution_time = 300` . Do think the upgrade helped the most though.

And just afterwards I found out more people were having issues with Laravel Valet on OSX Sierra. Found this awesome blog post on how to troubleshoot Valet [here](https://laravel-news.com/2016/09/troubleshooting-laravel-valet-on-macos-sierra/) at Laravel News.

Caddy error log is here: `~/.valet/Log/error.log`

And at `/usr/local/opt/php70/var/log/php-fpm` you can check for PHP errors.

In the Caddy log I found :

```
27/Sep/2016:16:11:55 +0300 [ERROR 502 /server.php] write tcp 127.0.0.1:80->127.0.0.1:49517: write: broken pipe
```

Article mentioned that an error 502 probably indicates PHP FPM Issues. 
When I checked for PHP FPM errors I saw:

```
[27-Sep-2016 16:48:00] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[27-Sep-2016 16:48:00] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[27-Sep-2016 16:48:00] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (48)
[27-Sep-2016 16:48:00] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

I bet that was the main issue. But now that I have a clean new Valet installed and a PHP FPM that does well I should be fine. And if not I know how to debug now!